# How to securely transfer to the server an email address that was authenticated on the browser?

Tags: oauth-2.0, hello.js

I am able to use the "hello.js" library, which implements the oauth2 protocol on the client, to obtain the email address for a user authenticated via a third-party app (Google and Facebook).

Of course it would be possible to send the email address to the server over HTTPS, but how can I prevent the exchange from being spoofed? That is, how can the server be assured that the email address being received from the browser is the one that was authenticated via the third-party app?

Perhaps the email address is somewhere in the message sent to the "redirect_uri", which passes thru the server on the way to the client, but if so, I can't find it. It's not in the GET or POST parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Dodson, the author of "hello.js", has been kind enough to answer this question for me on Gitter. He wrote:

> The client side web app needs to send the token (find it after login
>   with hello('facebook').getAuthResponse().access_token) back to your
>   server. This token can be used anywhere to make an API request to the
>   third party.

So the browser doesn't send the actual email address to the server. Instead, it sends the token, and then the server uses the token to ask the third-party app for the email address associated with that token.